# Cant set proper stacking of pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make an arrow with CSS only. I have problem with putting pseudo elemenents below the parent element. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I think that z-index is set properly.

```css
.down-arrow {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 2px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fbc52b;
    z-index: 100;
}

.down-arrow::before,
.down-arrow::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -3px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 5;
}

.down-arrow::before {
    bottom: -3px;
    background-color: #fbc52b;
}
.down-arrow::after {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<span class="down-arrow"></span>
```

Comment: add `position` property.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
.down-arrow {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 2px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fbc52b;
}

.down-arrow::before,
.down-arrow::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute
}

.down-arrow::before {
    background-color: #fbc52b;
    width: 9px;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 1px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    left: -7px;
}
.down-arrow::after {
    background-color: #fbc52b;
    width: 9px;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 1px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="down-arrow"></span>
```

Comment: it is not quite what I was asking about and what I need (arrows angle is not 45 degrees), but surely helpful.

Comment: If you want with 45 deg angle then please check above edited answer.

Comment: nice. I believe that `::before left: -6px;` and `::after left -1px` to make pseudo element stick together. I would also ask for some kind of explanation before I accept answer.